# Java thread equivalent of Python thread daemon mode

Tags: java, multithreading

In python I can set a thread to be a daemon, meaning if parent dies, the child thread automatically dies along with it.

Is there an equivalent in Java?

Currently I am starting a thread like this in Java, but the underlying child thread does not die and hang even if main thread exits

```
         executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
         executor.submit(() -> {
             while (true) {
                 //Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();

                 String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                 System.out.println("Hello " + threadName);
                 try {
                     Thread.sleep(1*1000);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     break;
                 }   

             }       
         });
```

Comment: Have you checked [Thread.setDaemon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-)?

Comment: In Java, the only difference between a daemon thread and a non-daemon thread is that the former won't keep the JVM alive. A daemon thread won't die because the thread that started it has died (unless, of course, the parent thread dying means there's no more non-daemon threads running).

Comment: In addition to @Slaw's comment; there is also no way to focibly kill a `Thread` in Java so such a thing could not be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're interacting with bare `Thread` you can use:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new MyJob());
thread.setDaemon(true);

thread.start();
```

In your example, there's `ExecutorService` that needs to be provided with `ThreadFactory` which should do the similar job - like this:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setDaemon(true);

        return thread;
    }
});
```

I would also recommend using `Guava`s `ThreadFactoryBuilder`:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(
        new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                .setDaemon(true)
                .build()
);
```

It eases setting the most common thread properties and allows for chaining multiple thread factories

*update*

As Slaw and Boris the Spider rightfully noticed - you have mentioned the behavior that would cause killing child-thread when parent-thread dies. There's nothing like that either in Python or Java. Daemon threads will be killed when all other non-daemon threads exited.

Comment: These are **not** the same thing. The OP says in Python that if the parent dies, the child is killed.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't think there's something like that in Python :) Thread's parent is the process spawning it

Comment: That is exactly my point. This answer is not only wrong it is misleading. Your comment about the thread's parents is of course incorrect.

Comment: it looks like my submit() isnt being called anymore after changing to using new ThreadFactory(). am i missing something?

Comment: @ealeon In a thread factory, you should pass `Runnable` to a `Thread` constructor (like that: `Thread thread = new Thread(r);`) I have updated the code

Comment: also are you saying, parent-thread dying is not an equivalent of all other non-daemon thread exiting? what are all non-daemon threads, if not just the parent? im confused

Comment: @ealeon If you start a thread `A` from your `main` thread and then a daemon thread `B` from within `A` (it can be seen like `main -> A -> B`). Then if `A` exits, `B` will still continue running until all non-daemon threads (i.e. `main` thread can be still running) exit (although `B`'s "parent thread" actually died).